# Calling a method of a class before creating an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Let's say we have a class, and we are calling it's method before creating an object:

```
class ParentClass:  
    def MyMethod(self):
        self.a=5
        print("I am Method")

ParentClass.MyMethod(ParentClass)
```

Why do we get a result?
Also, why `hasattr(ParentClass,'a')` is showing that instance variable is created?

Answer (score 2):

You get a result because you `ParentClass.MyMethod` evaluates to a regular `function` that takes one argument, which you supplied. The function doesn't care what the type of `self` is, as long as you can define an attribute named `a` for it. The result of `ParentClass.MyMethod(ParentClass)` is to add an attribute named `a` to `ParentClass`.

`ParentClass().MyMethod`, on the other hand, produces an instance of `method` that *wraps* the function, due to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). The *method*, when called, simply calls the function with the instance as the first argument and the rest of its own arguments. Because the function doesn't expect any more arguments, you would get a `TypeError`.